# Is it possible to shadow Vaadin Applications

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin

We have an enterprise web application built in Vaadin.  It would be useful to be able to provide remote training on a number of devices by shadowing the users browser.  Would it possible to build this sort of functionality in to the application itself?  Maybe there are tools out there to do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, although it could be possible to have this feature in Vaadin, it is not implemented right now, nor planed.

Vaadin RPC mechanism maintains synchronised set of states between the user session in server side and javascript in client side. In theory it could be possible to code some kind of protocol to synchronise two sessions in the server, and to send updates to both clients.

But it's not as trivial as exposed, since in client side certain widgets might have other states which are never sent to the server, because they only have meaning in the widget itself. That could be for example the case of a map or a chart, which the user could zoom or move without informing the server until something is required from it.

Comment: Thank you for this - maybe a browser plugin would be an option?

Comment: I don't know any tool for that, in a quick google search didn't found anything, if I found something I'll say.

Comment: Teamviewer allows you do to such mirroring of desktops or single windows, either for one user or for groups of users